# How do I solve this pointer-for loop in C?

Tags: c, string, loops, pointers

`regexp` and `src` are both strings, and `count` is a pointer to a counter used to scroll the string. It should get out as soon as `']'` is found in `regexp`, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
int inParent(char *src, char *regexp, int *count) {
    int check = 0;

    printf("%d", *count);
    for (*count = 0; *(regexp + *count) != ']'; *count + 1) {
        if (*(regexp + *count) == *src)
            check = 1;
    }

    if (check == 1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "it doesn't seem to be working".

Comment: `*count+1` does not change count.  Maybe `(*count)++`

Comment: Your `for` loop will overrun the bounds of `regexp` if that string does not, in fact, contain a `']'` character.

Comment: Also, `*(regexp+*count)` is difficult to read.  `regexp[*count]` is much easier to read and understand, and it means exactly the same thing.

Comment: And if it is intentional that you compare various characters from `regexp` to only the *first* character of `src`, without ever modifying that character, then the function overall would be clearer if the first argument was just the character you're looking for (as a `char`) not a pointer to that `char`.  That is: `int inParent(char c, const char *regexp, int *count)`.  You would of course also need to modify the callers correspondingly.

Comment: Is the final value of `*count` supposed to be the index of the first `']'` in `regexp` even when `*src` is found (earlier) in `regexp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your count is not incrementing.

```
int inParent(char *src, char *regexp, int *count) {
    int check = 0;
    printf("%d", *count);
    for (*count = 0; *(regexp + (*count)) != '\0'; *count += 1) {
        if (*(regexp + (*count)) == *src)
            check = 1;
    }

    if (check == 1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```